# OkHttp do not keep idle connections for keep alive duration

Tags: okhttp

Why it could be that OkHttp does not keep an idle connection in the pool for the keep-alive duration? That results in connection count spiking back and forth much faster than actual keep alive duration.

There's only one host with just 1 rps. `maxIdleConnections` is set to 20, `keepAlive` is set to 20 minutes. The latencies though might reach up to 2 seconds per call.

Connection count is spiking from 1 to 3 and back constantly, like every few minutes.

Answer (score 2):

Have you configured `maxIdleConnections` ? If you're hitting lots of hosts then OkHttp will close connections to stay within that limit.

https://square.github.io/okhttp/4.x/okhttp/okhttp3/-connection-pool/-init-/

Comment: There's only one host with just 1 rps. `maxIdleConnections` is set to 20, `keepAlive` is set to 20 minutes. The latencies though might reach up to 2 seconds per call.